# UDP receivers program priority?

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I have 2 identical programs running on same Linux host (Centos 7), listening to same UDP channel.  I haven't fiddle with their running priority (nice-ness).  The server is an 8-core box.  The 2 programs are running on the cpus on the same NUMA node.  It's just one starts after the other.  What determines the priority of which application will get the data first from the kernel buffer?  Is there anyways to change the priority?

Answer (score 0):

From what I found you can't.

Read
[Socket options SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT, how do they differ? Do they mean the same across all major operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t)

basically in linux it is random if you let multiple sockets listen on the same port.